# Lengthy sleep command not working in script

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, sleep, init.d, mksh

I've written a `su.d` script to periodically (every 4 hours) back up data from an app using a looped `sleep` command:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

(
  # Wait for boot to complete
  until [ "$(getprop sys.boot_completed)" ]
  do
    sleep 300
  done

  while true
  do
    (
      new_dir="/storage/emulated/0/temp/AppData/$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M')"
      mkdir -p $new_dir
      cp /data/data/com.example.app/files/*.json $new_dir

      echo "$(date '+%F %T') | app data backup OK!" >> /storage/emulated/0/su.d.log
    ) &

    sleep 14400 # 4 hours
  done
) &
```

In practice, the script backs up the data only after boot—not every 4 hours.

However, if I enter a remote shell via `adb` and leave it alone, then the data does get backed up every 4 hours.

How can I force the periodic backup without being permanently connected to a PC? (And why isn't it working as expected?)

---

#### EDITS

1. @Irfan Latif's comment gave me the idea of trying a different interpreter (busybox ash - `#!/system/xbin/sh`), but the result was the same. I'll try @mirabilos's daemonise suggestion (`sh -T- -c '...'`) next.
2. Tried @mirabilos's daemonise suggestion with the same result: backs up data only after boot.
3. Tried `nohup`:

   ```
   nohup /system/bin/sh -T- -c '...' >/dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```

   Same result.

Comment: I can't recall exactly but I had figured that out once. I think the problem was with `/system/bin/sh` (korn shell). It behaves unexpectedly when not connected to a terminal and forks a shell in background. For commandline, you can go for busybox `cron` to schedule tasks. For UI, use an app like Tasker.

Comment: You can go for cron daemon by simply creating a `crontabs` file. This seems a more appropriate solution for repeated tasks rather than using `shell` in background. All you need to run on boot is: `busybox crond -c /path/to/crontabs`. If you want to stick with shell thing, use `set -x` and `exec &>` to take logs of su.d script with timestamps to find when and why shell execution fails.

Comment: Man You can use alternatives, see here: <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482725/shell-is-it-possible-to-delay-a-command-without-using-sleep>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no success with `sleep`, I ended up going the [`crond`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747880/how-to-use-crontab-in-android) route, as suggested by @Irfan Latif:

- #### `/system/su.d/99crond  (-rwx------ root root)`

  ```
  #!/system/bin/sh

  # File: 99crond
  # Desc: Start cron daemon

  (
    # Wait for boot to complete
    until [ "$(getprop sys.boot_completed)" ]
    do
      sleep 2
    done

    # Symlink default cron dir to /data/local/crontabs
    mount -o remount,rw /
    mkdir -p /var/spool/cron
    ln -s /data/local/crontabs /var/spool/cron/crontabs
    mount -o remount,ro /

    crond -b

    echo "$(date '+%F %T') | su.d/99crond OK!" >> /storage/emulated/0/su.d.log
  ) &
  ```
- #### `/data/local/crontabs/root  (-rw------- root root)`

  ```
  # /data/local/crontabs/root: Android root user crontab

  SHELL=/system/bin/sh
  PATH=/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/data/local/bin

  #.--------------------------- Minute (M) (0--59)
  #|    .---------------------- Hour (H) (0--23, 0 = midnight)
  #|    |     .---------------- Day of Month (DoM) (1--31)
  #|    |     |     .---------- Month (MON) (1--12) OR jan,feb,mar, ...
  #|    |     |     |     .---- Day of Week (DoW) (0--6, Sunday = 0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue, ...
  #|    |     |     |     |
  #M    H     DoM   MON   DoW   COMMAND
  0     */4   *     *     *     /data/local/bin/cron_backup.sh
  #
  ```

  **FURTHER READING**

  - [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)
  - [What is the correct syntax to run cron every 4 hours?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39004/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-run-cron-every-4-hours)
  - [crontab(5) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)
- #### `/data/local/bin/cron_backup.sh  (-rwxr-xr-x root shell)`

  ```
  #!/system/bin/sh

  # File: cron_backup.sh
  # Desc: Back up app data (periodically with crond)

  new_dir="/storage/emulated/0/temp/AppData/$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M')"
  mkdir -p "$new_dir"
  cp /data/data/com.example.app/files/*.json "$new_dir"

  echo "$(date '+%F %T') | cron_backup.sh OK!" >> /storage/emulated/0/crond.log
  ```

---

As pointed out by @Ramast [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773268/9718438), these three files alone were not quite sufficient to get `crond` working: [`/system/etc/passwd`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) is also required for user *root* to be recognised, so...

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo "root:x:0:0:root:/data:/system/bin/sh" >> /system/etc/passwd
chmod 644 /system/etc/passwd
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

After all that is done the data gets backed up periodically as desired.

Answer (score 3):

If it’s the terminal thing @IrfanLatif wrote, try this:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# run a command block in the background, detached from all terminals
/system/bin/sh -T- -c '
    # Wait for boot to complete
    until [ "$(getprop sys.boot_completed)" ]; do
        sleep 300
    done

    while true; do
        (
            new_dir="/storage/emulated/0/temp/AppData/$(date '\''+%Y%m%d-%H%M'\'')"
            mkdir -p "$new_dir"
            cp /data/data/com.example.app/files/*.json "$new_dir"

            echo "$(date '\''+%F %T'\'') | app data backup OK!" >>/storage/emulated/0/su.d.log
        ) &

        sleep 14400 # 4 hours
    done
'
```

The `-T-` option tells the shell to `daemon()`ise, that is, replace stdin, stdout, stderr with `/dev/null` and double-fork the command into the background. Perhaps this helps.

I don’t have an off-hand idea why this would otherwise not work. Full disclosure: I’m the `mksh` developer.

Answer (score 1):

My comment does not work too. I have understood, `sleep` does not work then screen is off.

You should perhaps keep the system awaked for `sleep` command to be working.