# ADB root shell always waits for background job before exit

Tags: adb, shell, superuser

I want to run a process in background and close the terminal, so the process remains active.
I need to run the process as root. Since `adb root` doesn't work for me, I use `adb shell; $ su` to gain root privileges.
I expect this to work: `command &; exit` or `nohup command &; exit`. It actually runs the process, but `exit` just waits for the process to terminate. I also tried to run `sleep 10 &; exit`, and exactly, the shell exits after 10 seconds (when all jobs are done).
This happens only when `su` shell is used. It means that when I run `adb shell; $ sleep 50 &; exit` it exits immediately as expected. The problem also happens when I use `su` from termux (android package terminal). And also on my other device as well.

I can just kill the terminal, it does the job (process remains active as I wanted), but what is the proper way to exit the root shell when there are active jobs?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: On common Linux I would use `screen` or `tmux` to create a terminal you can disconnect at any time.

Comment: It's a known issue I explained [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/1544#issuecomment-504843590) years back. Related questions: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216266/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207975/218526). Also beware of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221420/218526).